# Why does being an LP in uniswap take a fee?

Tags: uniswapv3

I deposit 10k USDC into uniswap as an lp for the current tick spacing as a range order, i.e. I'm trying to provide one sided liquidity as a limit order.

No trades occur, thus no fees accrue. I decrease my full liquidity based on the current liquidity passed from the LP NFT token's position.

I get 9999.999999 USDC.

Why is this? I'm assuming it's a rounding issue.

Comment: Seems like the 0.01% fee.

Comment: (10k w/ 6 decimal places) is 10000000000*.0001 (0.01%) = 1000000.0 / 10 ** 6 = is $1 and this is $0.000001 which is much less.